# Audible alert in remote location?

Tags: audio, remote, alert

We have some remote offices - HQ in UK, offices in Ireland and France.  The remote offices want to be able to make a noise in our HQ to catch our attention.  Is there a simple, cheap and reliable way to do this?

Things I've thought about - Is it possible to send a command to a PC that controls our tannoy, or set up a speaker that can make a sound via a remote command?  I don't know how this can be done simply - for example the remote offices just have a big button they press, and it will always ring our office (if via a PC, what if it was turned off, muted etc).  Will an Alexa do the job?  An online platform?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about a phone?

Comment: Just normal phone wouldn't be loud enough or distinctive enough, we want this to make a fairly loud noise so everyone near realises.  Maybe we could program a buzzer that can be activated by phone or something though.

Comment: "Just normal phone wouldn't be loud enough or distinctive enough" - you can associate ringtones with callers. You may have a phone only for such calls and connect it to a loudspeaker... There is already a tool for your need, why do you want to reinvent it?

Comment: Not reinventing, I just don't know all the options or if there are simpler alternatives.  The system that does all the settings for our phone system reminds me of Putty - ie. it's not very simple to set up.  I'll have a think along those lines though, thanks.

Comment: Just occured to me that I could set up a relay that is triggered by phone system that can ring a bell or buzzer.  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have VoIP handsfree phones, many phones can receive a multicast audio stream and play it through the speaker, turning your phone system into a public address system (often with an option that anyone can pick up a phone and turn the all-call into a private phone call).

Otherwise use a VoIP Paging Adapter such as [Snom PA1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jC2Mqr1PRU), this has a built in 4 watt amplifier which would drive a speaker to cover one office or a reception area, or could be wired into an existing public address system. Snom PA1 will receive either SIP calls like an ordinary VoIP phone, or IP multicast. Ubiquity makes a wifi access point which has integrated IP speakers. Cyberdata is another manufacturer of VoIP Paging Adapters.